# Customize Node-Red Dashboard UI

Tags: node-red

I am trying to find the files to customize the appearance of the Dashboard UI for Node-Red, without any success!! I am using Ubuntu Mate.

Clean question: How do I add a theme or edit an existing one for Dashboard UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Themes are not currently editable from the deployed version of the `node-red-dashboard`. You will have to pull the project from github and edit it then rebuild the package.

Details on how to build the `node-red-dashboard` package are on it's github [here](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-dashboard) under the "Developers" heading.

This explains how to build the minified version of the CSS and javascript used to display the widgets after you've edited the CSS

Comment: Ok, so I have made some changes according to the readme file. Then it says I should use the command "gulp", but when doing this I get gulp: command not found..
Any ideas for this?

Comment: Update: No need to use gulp, seems to update itself anyway.

Comment: Install gulp maybe?